# Android Accessibility for Context menu on Edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, talkback, accessibility

I am new to accessibility stuff in android and can't really understand what's happening in the below case.

I have got a custom edittext in a custom AlertDialog, I have a requirement to select all the text in the edittext when the dialog is shown. To achieve this, I am using

```
editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true)
```

Because of this, My Accessibility Talkback speaks **action:share** whenever the edit text is focused. Initially, I thought this is because of the local context menu of the edittext and then I disabled the local context menu using below code

```
editText.customSelectionActionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {}
    }
```

Even then I could not get rid of the Talkback speaking "action:share". Further, I override the "onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo" function on edittext to debug what actions are allocated to the Talkback and I see that some Unknown action has the label "Share" (refer to the screenshot below)

[image]

I am able to remove the "**action:share**" with the code below, but not sure if this is the right way and will have any side effects

```
editText.setAccessibilityDelegate(object : AccessibilityDelegate() {
        override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host: View?, info: AccessibilityNodeInfo?) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
            info?.actionList?.clear()// removes the action share
        }
    })
```

Please advise, If there is any better way for handling actions for Accessibility in Android.

Note: I tested this on Pixel 1(7.1) and Samsung Note 8(7.1.1)